# Does Send mail can turn on external recursion in BIND DNS Server?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind, sendmail, recursion

I've a Ubuntu 10.04 package from Godaddy, It includes BIND and Sendmail pre-installed.

Normally recursion enabled for Internal DNS queries and recursion is disabled for External DNS queries. (Please correct me if I'm wrong here)

But I found that my server has both Internal and External recursion turned on.

Is there any chance that Sendmail program can turn on External recursion?

Or any other (very common) program can turn the recursion on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sendmail cannot turn on recursion in BIND. Sendmail uses the standard [resolver APIs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname) which don't provide the feature you want.

---

Godaddy [say](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1184/what-risks-are-associated-with-recursive-dns-queries)

> NOTE: We do not allow recursive DNS to run on dedicated or virtual
>   dedicated servers unless it runs locally and for a specific IP range.
>   If we find your server running an improper configuration of recursive
>   DNS, we will exercise our right to suspend your account. The account
>   will remain suspended until arrangements are made to turn off
>   recursive DNS.

Comment: Any other program can turn the recursion on?

Comment: @Mithum: Read [this](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1184/what-risks-are-associated-with-recursive-dns-queries) - why do you want recursion on?

Comment: I'm getting spam mail notices about my serevr, but I'm not sure spam mails are send from my server, but I'm suspecting a DNS Cache poisoning attack

Comment: @Mithum, ensure your sendmail config doesn't allow relaying. A spate of SPAM notices often just results from forged "from" addresses originating elsewhere in the Internet. Iterative DNS is not the cause.

Comment: I'm confused that the timing of the SPAM 'failure messages' I received, it matches with the server swich on/off or Hardware firewall turn on/off timing

Comment: @Mithun: start a new question - provide details: sanitized SPAM mail notice INCLUDING ALL HEADERS - details of mail handling (where MX records point etc).